# Updating a mysql table with a csv file. I need debuggers

Tags: php, mysql, file, debugging, csv

I'm trying to allow someone to update a table "survey" with contents from a csv by uploading an edited file. But every time I submit the file I get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`Record_ID`=Record ID, `Agreement`= 'Agreement (Q2)',`1(Q_1)`= '1 (Q1_1)',`3 (Q' at line 1

There's something wrong with my query and I can't figure it out.

```
    <?php 

//connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("genydb",$connect); //select the table
//
if (isset($_FILES['csv'])){
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES["csv"]['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
  while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",","'")){

 mysql_query("UPDATE `survey` SET(`Record_ID`='".addslashes($data[0])."', `Agreement`= '".addslashes($data[1])."',`1(Q_1)`= '".addslashes($data[2])."', `3 (Q4)`='".addslashes($data[3])."', `2 (Q3)`='".addslashes($data[4])."', `4 (Q5)`='".addslashes($data[5])."', `5 (Q6)`='".addslashes($data[6])."', `7 (Q8)`='".addslashes($data[7])."', `6 (Q7)`='".addslashes($data[8])."', `8 (Q9)`='".addslashes($data[9])."', `9 (Q10)`='".addslashes($data[10])."', `10 (Q11)`='".addslashes($data[11])."', `11 (Q12)`='".addslashes($data[12])."', `13 (Q14_1)`= '".addslashes($data[13])."'")or die(mysql_error()); 

    }
    //

    //redirect
    header('Location: imports.php?success=1'); die;

}

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET['success'])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input type="file"  name="csv" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Remove parenthesis after "SET"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have to use `(` here . it stands alone there this parenthese.

```
     mysql_query("UPDATE `survey` SET(`Record_ID`='".addslashes($....
                                     ^^----------here
```

replace it to

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE `survey` SET `Record_ID`='".addslashes($....
```

**also** : its recommended to use `mysql_real_escape_string` before inserting variables inside mysql query.

**AND** : recommended `MYSQLI` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` as its already deprecated.

Comment: Also dont use `addslashes` use `mysql_real_escape_string` or Switch to prepared statements using PDO or MySQLi

Comment: okay I got rid of the parentheses but now it's giving me the error "Duplicate entry '1 (Q1_1)' for key '1(Q_1)'" I thought with update its supposed to overlook those things. Would switching to mysqli/pdo fix that?

Comment: i dont know your table , you didnt show anything of your table but i guess you have other column wich called `1(Q_1)` but as i saw your other columns maybe you mean `1 (Q_1)` with space between 1 and `(`. like others.

Comment: 1(Q_1) is a column in my table 1 (Q1_1) is a header in the csv file and gets inputted into the database under 1(Q_1)

Comment: yes i said check for the space `1 (Q_1)` not like `1(Q_1)` change your own column by this `1 (Q_1)` look for space between 1 and (

Comment: there's no space in the column name in my code or in the table its this `1(Q_1)'

Comment: this error `"Duplicate entry '1 (Q1_1)' for key '1(Q_1)'` it means that you tried to enter two values in that column `1(Q_1)`

Comment: check your file csv and sure you will find two values for that column